# applescript, move folder and its contents to trash

Tags: applescript

Anyone can point out how to move the folder and its contents to the trash folder on mac?

I tried this:

```
 tell application "Finder"
      set sourceFolder to POSIX file "/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework"
      set destFolder to POSIX file "/Users/XXX/.Trash"
      move entire contents of folder sourceFolder to folder destFolder
 end tell
```

The contents are all gone, but not the folder which is SDL.framework.

Also, when I tested the files removed to the trash folder, right click on the files, no "put back" opinion. Anyone knows why?

Thanks.

LJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can and should simply use the Finder's `delete` command to move items to the trash:

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
  set sourceFolder to POSIX file "/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework"
  delete sourceFolder  # move to trash
end tell
```

This will use the system's normal trashing mechanism and thus also enable you to put the item back later - you were trying to bypass that mechanism with direct folder manipulation.

As for why the source folder itself was not removed: as the name of the `entire contents` property suggests, a folder's *contents* are referenced, not including the folder *itself*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I always think delete will remove the file , instead of putting them to trash. Thank you again, also for your explanation.

Comment: @user1558064: My pleasure. Allow me a general tip, for both my benefit and that of future readers: If an answer _solved_ your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you found it at least _helpful_ (you may have already done this here), please up-vote it by clicking the up-arrow icon.

Comment: Oddly, when i try the Finder's "delete" command under 10.10.2, it gets deleted immediately, not moved to the trash. The item is an app in a custom folder.

Comment: @mklement0 - now I can't reproduce it either, any more. Nevermind my comment. If you upvote this reply, I know you've read it and then I'll delete my comments as they're not helping

Answer (score 0):

just replace the line
      delete sourceFolder  # move to trash
with

### move sourceFolder to the trash

tell application "Finder"
  set sourceFolder to POSIX file "/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework"
  move sourceFolder to the trash
end tell